# ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback onChildDraw

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

I have problem with to fast moving of rows in my RecyclerView.

if i moving with them that fast so one get moved faster thatn other two of them propably... than manytimes my background is left there... sometimes even whole view...(propably if i move with my finger a bit back which cancale onswipe...)

Is there any solution to this bug?
or am i stupid and did something badly...

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback preparedSimpleCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        final int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        switch (direction) {
            case ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT:
                preparedToCompleted(viewHolder.getLayoutPosition(), false);
            break;
            case ItemTouchHelper.LEFT:
                preparedToProcessing(viewHolder.getLayoutPosition(), false);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        new RecyclerViewSwipeDecorator.Builder(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
                .addSwipeLeftBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.blue_link))
                .addSwipeLeftActionIcon(R.drawable.ic_delete_white_24dp)
                .addSwipeRightBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorAccent))
                .addSwipeRightActionIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .create()
                .decorate();

        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }
};
```

This is itemtoutch helper... and on swipe it call long void which start is :

```
public void preparedToCancelled (int position, Boolean error) {
    final JSONObject row = (JSONObject) preparedRecycler.Apirows.get(position);
    if (mainActivity.addAction()) {             
       final Long id = (Long) row.get("id");......
```

and notifying by this:

```
            for (int x = 0; x < preparedRecycler.Apirows.size(); ++x) {
                JSONObject y = (JSONObject) preparedRecycler.Apirows.get(x);
                if (y.get("id") == id) {
                    preparedRecycler.Apirows.remove(x);
                    //preparedRecycler.notifyItemRemoved(x);
                    preparedRecycler.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
```

i tryed notifying both removed and dataSetChange are having this isue...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcCyD.jpg)

Refreshing or adding new row to crashed position does not repair that background

**UPDATE:**
I checked that view position and it is actualy -1 which means it does not existed... how can i prevented that.. ? i can not even remove that row becouse of that